# How to create Json RPC web service in asp.net

Tags: angularjs, web-services

How to create json rpc web service that will get the record at server side and store into sql server

Comment: Have a look at [JSON RPC.NET](https://github.com/Astn/JSON-RPC.NET) or [Jayrock](https://atifaziz.github.io/projects/jayrock/)

Comment: I don't understand how to use jayrock?